# Best practice for setting up kubernetes cluster on GPU workstation

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes

I like to find out the current best practice for setting up a kubernetes cluster on a Dell Alienware Aurora workstation running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for GPU based tensorflow workload.  This will be a staging ground for my services/containers before I deploy them to a full-blown k8s cluster.   I am not sure what the correct strategy for such a setup looks like.  Here are some possibilities:

1. Minikube with virtualbox driver, worker node in VM
2. Minikube with --vm-driver=none, relying on docker
3. Kubeadm with scheduling pods on master enabled
4. Kubeadm-dind (docker in docker)

**Update**: added kubeadm options.  Can someone also comment on the docker in docker solution.  Will services/pods work seamlessly from docker in docker setup to multi-node remote machines/cloud instance setups?

Would love to hear from the kubernetes experts or someone familiar with tensorflow/GPU workloads on a single physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with 2 or 3 vm's and using kubeadm. You'll have real cluster to play with. There's some vagrant/ansible playbooks out there. GPU/Tensorflow is kinda new, so play ;)

Comment: thank you, I included kubeadm in my question, hopefully someone will have a more complete answer.  I'm a ML researcher really have very little time to spend on devops...